# iOS keyboard prevent UIButton from reacting

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, keyboard

[image]

I have 3 views illustrated as in the image. View 2 is in View 1, and View 3 is in View 2. Something weird is happening:

When I click the textfield in View 3, the keyboard opens, and at this time the button in View 2 no longer reacts. When I click button 2 with keyboard open, its color changes (notifies me it is clickable), but the event is never fired. If I don't click the textfield to open keyboard, button functions normally, color changes and the event is fired.

However, button 1 in View1 always works normally, doesn't get affected by the keyboard. It took me a while to find out it's the keyboard that makes the difference but I just can't figure out why. Could someone help me a little?

Comment: you might need to debug it in the Debug View Hierarchy mode

Comment: wow this is cool feature, thank you for pointing it out, but I still don't see what's wrong there.

Comment: that one would show you if you have a view blocking the view you're trying to tap on, also you can change values for your views there dynamically in the run time and see how it looks and stuff. As for your problem, it's hard to say without the code.

Comment: Can you provide a demo project?

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue. One other thing I noticed, that when keyboard is open is blocks the buttons. When the keyboard is hidden, the buttons react normally again.